# Why Didn't Severus Disapparate In the Shrieking Shack?

Tags: harry-potter

I do believe that Severus knew he was in danger in the Shrieking Shack. Harry even wondered if he sensed danger. Voldemort said to him,

> I have thought long and hard, Severus… do you know why I have called you back from the battle?

If you put two and two together, Snape must have known that he was in danger. He must have known that the fight was almost over, because Dumbledore told him to tell Harry (indirectly) that he was a horcrux. He had orders, so why couldn’t he just disapparate into the castle?

Comment: Good question, if I had to guess I'd say Voldemort is smart enough to cast an 'Aura of Anti-Disapparation'

Comment: If Snape had run, it wouldn't have bought him much. Look how much good it did Karkaroff.

Comment: I agree, Snape knew what was going to happen, but he also knew he was playing a role in keeping Harry alive, he had to let Voldemort believe that he would become master of the Elder wand if he won it from Snape. Snape is much braver and knows what needs to be done for the greater good

Comment: @BP_Phoenix "for the greater good", nice.

Comment: Remember, it's impossible to apparate or disapparate to & from Hogwarts.  In the movie, only person that was able to do so was Dumbledore.  Unless that changed after he died(I don't think it's mentioned anywhere that it did) it would have been impossible for Snape to get back to the castle.

Comment: @Robert - "Being headmaster has its privileges". Snape was headmaster at the time, even if he had "done a bunk".

Comment: @JohnP That's in the film. And your suggestion that he was headmaster at the time is false; if it was true he would have had a portrait put in place immediately. Rowling said she imagines Harry would have made sure to have one put up but no he wasn't technically headmaster then. It's true that in OotP he does lift the restriction in one part of the castle for practising/learning but not really relevant; remember in HBP they fly to the Astronomy Tower from Hogsmeade (where they Apparated to from the rock by the cave).

Comment: @Pryftan the books and Pottermore both disagree with you.

Comment: @JohnP, I believe the correct quote is "Being me has its advantages".  There's nothing to suggest that Dumbledore's ability to bypass the restriction against Apparition was something automatically granted to all headmasters.

Comment: ... and even if it is, [technically Snape had abdicated](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149095/5930).

Comment: @JohnP He absolutely didn't have his portrait put up because he wasn't headmaster. The book does not disagree there and neither does Rowling. See what HarryJohnston also said. The fact remains you're wrong; one place (though not the direct quote it's still been said elsewhere): http://www.the-leaky-cauldron.org/2007/10/20/j-k-rowling-at-carnegie-hall-reveals-dumbledore-is-gay-neville-marries-hannah-abbott-and-scores-more/

Comment: @Pryftan So...the whole section in the Daily Prophet as told (pages 225-226) in the book is just a lie? He was appointed headmaster, and remained so until he left/died. And Pottermore also concurs. Or chapter 33 where Dumbledore addresses snape as headmaster, the epilogue, etc. Maybe the question you should be asking is why he didnt apparently get a portrait?

Comment: @HarryJohnston If he was never headmaster, how did he abdicate? You can't abdicate from a position you do not hold.

Comment: @JohnP, I disagree with the premise that he was never headmaster.

Answer (score 15):

short answer:

Because (like Harry) **Snape was supposed to die by Voldemort's hand** (all part of Dumbledore's plan)

Both Harry and Snape **must** only find out about their inevitable deaths **at the last moment**, because both Harry and Snape **might not** have the strength to accept their impending deaths.

> deathly hollows chapter the prince's tale
>
> “Harry must not know, not until the last moment, not until it 
>   is necessary, otherwise how could he have the strength to do what 
>   must be done?”

Long answer (and a vindication for Snape)

**Note** that there is nothing in canon about what was inside Snape's mind in the Shrieking
Shack.This will be speculation of Snape's thoughts based on the sequence of events in the shack and Snape's memories in the Pensieve

1. Snape was looking at the enchanted cage around Nagini when he realized that **Dumbledore's plan has come true** - Voldemort was now protecting Nagini. - Snape **must now** tell Harry that he is also a horcrux.

> *deathly hollows chapter the prince's tale* (scene where Harry was looking at Snape's memories in the Pensieve)
>
> There will come a time when Lord Voldemort will seem 
>   to fear for the life of his snake.”
>
> “For Nagini?” Snape looked astonished.
>
> “Precisely. If there comes a time when Lord Voldemort **stops sending 
>   that snake forth** to do his bidding, but **keeps it safe** beside him 
>   under magical protection, then, I think, it will be safe to **tell Harry**.”
>
> *deathly Hollows chapter the elder wand* (scene where Harry was spying on Snape and Voldemort)
>
> And for a moment Harry saw **Snape’s profile: His eyes were fixed 
>   upon the coiling snake in its enchanted cage**. 
>   “No, my Lord, but I beg you will let me return. Let me find 
>   Potter.”

2. Then Voldemort started talking about how the Elder wand was not doing extraordinary magic. Hinting that the wand does not recognize him as it's master.

> *deathly hollows chapter the elder wand*
>
> “I sought a third wand, Severus. The Elder Wand, the Wand of 
>   Destiny, the Deathstick. I took it from its previous master. I took it 
>   from the grave of Albus Dumbledore.”
>
> And now Snape looked at Voldemort, and **Snape’s face was like a 
>   death mask.** It was marble white and so still that when he spoke, it 
>   was a shock to see that anyone lived behind the blank eyes...
>
> ...“Perhaps you already know it? You are a clever man, after all, 
>   Severus. You have been a good and faithful servant, and I regret 
>   what must happen.”
>
> “My Lord —”
>
> “The Elder Wand cannot serve me properly, Severus, because I 
>   am not its true master. The Elder Wand belongs to the wizard who 
>   killed its last owner.

3. **Then and only then**, did **Snape realize** - **this was also part of Dumbledore's plan** (why Dumbledore said “...You must kill me.”)

> *deathly hollows chapter the princes tale* (scene Snape and Dumbledore talking about Malfoy)
>
> ...of course, there is only one thing to be done if we are to save him 
>   from Lord Voldemort’s wrath.”
>
> Snape raised his eyebrows and his tone was sardonic as he asked,
>
> “Are you intending to let him kill you?”
>
> “Certainly not. **You must kill me.**”

4. Snape must have realized, **he too** must die in order **to make Voldemort believe** that his death will make Voldemort the true master of the Elder Wand.

   (why is it necessary for Voldemort to believe? So that Voldemort **will not ask anybody else to kill Harry**, ***Voldemort must be led to believe*** that that killing Dubledore's killer (Snape) will make him the master of the Unbeatable Wand. A wand that he can use to ***finally*** defeat and kill Harry.)

> Deathly Hollows chapter the prince's tale
>
> “So the boy . . . the boy must die?” asked Snape quite calmly.
>
> “And **Voldemort** himself **must do it**, Severus. ***That is essential***.”

5. Snape must have also realized that Dumbledore did not trust him to **calmly accept sacrificing himself.** (same as Harry)

> *deathly hollows chapter the prince's tale*
>
> “Harry must not know, not until the last moment, not until it 
>   is necessary, otherwise how could he have the strength to do what 
>   must be done?”

6. **Snape** must have **realized he is in the same boat as Harry**. The full extent of Dumbledore's plan - **for both of them to die** - and for both of them **to realize the necessity of their death,** only at the last moment.
7. Snape must have also realized that since Voldemort called him here to kill him, then Voldemort is already prepared for any escape he might attempt.

So Snape could not disapparate because he was conflicted - he realizes that **he must die** for Dumbledore's plan to work - but he still has to tell Harry that he is also a horcrux.

***Additional Edits slightly off topic*** - for Dumbledore's thought process:

Some canon background first.

> from deathly Hollows chapter: King's Cross
>
> “But you **expected** him to go after the wand?”
>
> “I have been ***sure*** that he would try, ***ever since*** your wand beat 
>   Voldemort’s in the ***graveyard of Little Hangleton***. 
>   At first, he was afraid that you had conquered him by superior skill. Once he had 
>   **kidnapped Ollivander**, however, he discovered the existence of the 
>   twin cores.
>
> ...naturally set out to 
>   find the one wand that, they said, would **beat any other.**
>
> ...He ***believes*** that the Elder Wand removes his last weakness and 
>   makes him ***truly invincible.*** Poor Severus . . .”

.

> from Half-blood prince chapter Draco's Detour (Note Dumbledore **still alive**)
>
> “Talking of Diagon Alley,” said Mr. Weasley, “looks like **Ollivander's gone too.**”
>
> “The wandmaker?” said Ginny, looking startled.
>
> “That’s the one. Shop’s empty. No sign of a struggle. No one knows whether he left voluntarily or was kidnapped.”

My interpretation: As early as "Goblet of Fire" (while Dumbledore was still alive) Dumbledore is ***sure*** that Voldemort will go after the wand. And Ollivander's abduction  ***reinforced*** the idea that **Voldemort was looking for a wand to defeat and kill Harry.**

Now for the **speculation** of Dumbledore's plans and **scenarios** (in Dumbledore's mind):

Short Answer: Dumbledore **intends** to turn the Elder wand (Unbeatable wand) **into a trap** for Voldemort

Long Answer (with scenarios):

Voldemort steals the wand from Dumbledore's grave (thinking and **"believing"** that stealing the wand **will be enough** to make him the wand's master).

- end results:
- Snape would **"not"** have to die (***preferable outcome*** - in Dumbledore's mind).
- Voldemort **won't order anybody else** to kill Harry. Voldemort **"believes"** that he ***owns the Unbeatable Wand*** and **Voldemort himself** will **want to kill Harry** (which is the **essential part of Dumbledore's plan**).

Voldemort steals the wand **"but" eventually deduces** that he needs to kill Snape (Dumbledore's killer) to gain the Unbeatable Wand's loyalty.

- end results:
- Snape has to die (regrettable to Dumbledore's mind of course, **but necessary**)
- Voldemort **won't order anybody else** to kill Harry. Voldemort **"believes"** that he ***owns the Unbeatable Wand*** and **Voldemort himself** will **want to kill Harry** (which is the **essential part of Dumbledore's plan**).

on another tack:

**Malfoy** succeeds in killing Dumbledore, then Voldemort steals the wand **"but" eventually deduces** that he needs to kill Malfoy (Dumbledore's killer) to gain the wands loyalty.

- end results:
- Snape would "not" have to die (fortunate for Snape).
- Voldemort **won't order anybody else** to kill Harry. Voldemort **"believes"** that he ***owns the Unbeatable Wand*** and **Voldemort himself** will **want to kill Harry** (which is the **essential part of Dumbledore's plan**).

But, Dumbledore cannot allow an innocent child (Malfoy) to die for his plan. That is "one of the reasons" ***(but not the "only" reason)*** why he "asked" Snape to kill him.

***Additional Edit 3***: slightly off topic

With regards to Dumbledore's **intent** on whether Snape should own the wand after 
Dumbledore's death (see the quotes below for reference)

> Deathly Hallows chapter the Flaw in the plan
>
> “He killed —”
>
> “Aren’t you listening? Snape never beat Dumbledore! Dumbledore’s 
>   death was planned between them! **Dumbledore intended to die 
>   undefeated,** the wand’s last true master! If all had gone as planned, 
>   the wand’s power would have died with him, because it had never 
>   been won from him!”

.

> Deathly Hallows chapter King's Cross
>
> He believes that the Elder Wand removes his last weakness and 
>   makes him truly invincible. Poor Severus . . .”
>
> “If you planned your death with Snape, **you meant *him* to end 
>   up with the Elder Wand**, didn’t you?”
>
> “I admit that was my intention,” said Dumbledore, “but it did 
>   not work as I intended, did it?”
>
> “No,” said Harry. “That bit didn’t work out.”

The discrepancy is whether Dumbledore intended Snape to be the wand's master.

My speculation is the **first quote should take precedence** since it is more specific.

The second quote **should actually be read as** “If you planned your death with Snape, you 
**meant him *(Voldemort)* to end up with the Elder Wand**, didn’t you?”

I realize using the word ***"him"*** in the second quote is confusing based on this thread 
[What were Dumbledore's actual intentions for the Elder Wand?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25292/what-were-dumbledores-actual-)
intentions-for-the-elder-wand

No, I'm not a grammar teacher nor a book editor :)

My speculation is that it was **only in King's Cross chapter** that Harry **realized** that 
Voldemort was **supposed to end up with the wand**. Harry also needed to confirm this with 
Dumbledore since **only Dumbledore has the complete specifics of his own plan**.

Harry realized that Dumbledore **planned to turn the wand into a trap**. A trap designed to 
exploit Voldemort's desire to get an Unbeatable wand to kill Harry.

On another tack:

Dumbledore has a reason **not to reveal** to Snape his entire plan:

> Deathly Hallows chapter The Prince's tale (Pensieve scene Snape and Dumbledore talking)
>
> “I prefer ***not*** to put all of my secrets in one basket, particularly 
>   not a basket that spends so much time dangling on the arm of Lord 
>   Voldemort.”
>
> “Which I do on your orders!”...

and

> Deathly Hallows chapter The Prince's tale (Pensieve scene Snape and Dumbledore talking)
>
> “After you have killed me, Severus —”
>
> “You **refuse to tell me everything**, yet you expect that small service of me!” snarled 
>   Snape, and real anger flared in the thin face 
>   now. “You take a great deal for granted, Dumbledore! Perhaps I have 
>   changed my mind!”
>
> “You gave me your word, Severus. And while we are talking about 
>   services you owe me, I thought you agreed to keep a close eye on 
>   our young Slytherin friend?”
>
> Snape looked angry, mutinous. Dumbledore sighed.
>
> “Come to my office tonight, Severus, at eleven, and **you shall not complain** that I have no confidence in you. . . .”

Comment: Well written up, but Dumbledore's plan for the elder wand was for it to be nobodies master- Dumbledore asked Snape to kill him so he would die unvanquished, this went wrong when Draco disarmed him. Based on that (and the fact that the alternative is evil), I don't think Dumbledore intended Snape to die. I'm on mobile so I cant find the quote, but I believe this is discussed in 'Kings cross'.

Comment: @Crow T Robot Kindly elaborate on the purpose of Dumbledore dying unvanguished (does it stop Voldemort from killing Snape). Also please elaborate "(and the fact that the alternative is evil)"

Comment: Your answer was written nicely. Obvious research has been put into it, etc, etc. Your answer about Severus's death being planned by Dumbledore is purely speculation. All canon answers you stated in quotes are for other people; Harry and Dumbledore. For this reason, i do not see this making sense. However, It was said in the chapter Kings Cross. "If you planned your death with Snape, you meant him to end up with the Elder Wand, didn't you?" " I admit that was my intention,"

Comment: @Jake  Kindly elaborate on the purpose of Dumbledore dying unvanquished (does it stop Voldemort from killing Snape)

Comment: @tls are you asking me to elaborate, or saying that I elaborated?

Comment: @Jake elaborate

Comment: @tls I'm sorry? I don't really understand the question. I merely said that Dumbledore's intention was for Severus to acquire the Elder Wand.

Comment: @Jake thanks :). When you say "aquire" - do you mean, you interpret the book as saying Dumbledore intends for Snape to become the new master of the wand?

Comment: To everyone. I'm going to add some speculations on Dubledore's reasoning, I think people don't want the impression that Dumbledore intended Snape's death.

Comment: I finally found the quote I think @CrowTRobot was talking about, Deathly Hallows, Ch36, Harry says to Voldemort, "Aren’t you listening? Snape never beat Dumbledore! Dumbledore’s death was planned between them! Dumbledore intended to die undefeated, the wand’s last true master! If all had gone as planned, the wand’s power would have died with him, because it had never been won from him!"

Comment: Ok just so I know how people "interpret" the book; is Snape supposed to be the master of the wand or not? Because I'm seeing two interpretations on comments.

Comment: @tls, sounds like a good question to ask on this site :)

Comment: mikeazo thanks :) initial google search shows question asked by @NominSim http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25292/what-were-dumbledores-actual-intentions-for-the-elder-wand but no accepted answer. The only way I can make the two quotes reconcile is to slightly change the first quote to read “If you planned your death with Snape, you meant him "(Voldemort)" to end up with the Elder Wand, didn’t you?” I don't know the protocol for this - can I answer NominSim question even tho it was asked 2 years ago?

Comment: To everyone, added short version summary of Dumbledore's plan/scenarios

Comment: Additional edit 3 appended about wand ownership discrepancy (hopefully my last edit). Oh my aching head. Somebody yell Obliviate :)

Comment: @tls I already said the quote. "If you planned your death with Snape, you meant him to end up with the Elder Wand, didn't you?" "I admit that was my intention." This is canon and you can find it at the end of Kings Cross, Deathly Hallows.

Answer (score 9):

Since I disagree with the idea that Snape's death was planned by Dumbledore, I'm going to suggest an alternative and far simpler solution. You've said "Snape must have known he was in danger", and therefore he should have fled. But you neglect to consider that Snape was constantly betraying a mind-reading, sadistic, extremely powerful dark wizard who showed zero mercy to both his followers and his enemies. *Snape was always in danger.*

If he had been the type to break, or panic, Snape would have been killed long ago. Every single time he met Voldemort he must have had to fight the creeping paranoia.

*What if he knows...*

Every time he began a sadistic monologue describing how he treated traitors, or talked about how Snape was so *loyal*...

*What if he knows...*

Every time he began to raise his wand...

*What if he knows...*

In short, while Snape is around Voldemort every single breath could be his last, and he knows it. The sort of man who would have Disapparated when Voldemort began to get sinister would never have been able to infiltrate his ranks, or convince him he was still loyal after 14 years of working for Albus Dumbledore (can you even imagine that conversation?).

It is for this reason that Harry describes him as the bravest man he ever knew, and it is for this reason that he didn't Disapparate from the Shack that night.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are several reasons for him not Disapparating in the Shrieking Shack.

If you consider only the books, then he simply couldn't disapparate. In the Half Blood Prince when Harry and Dumbledore go to destroy the Horcrux, Dumbledore himself can't disapparate from the inside, having to go to Hogsmeade to do so. He claims that no one, not even the headmaster can do this.

Regarding only the movies, the disapparating rule is dismissed for the headmasters,  Dumbledore says to Harry that being headmaster has certain perks. At the time of Severus encounter he was still headmaster so apparently he could disapparate. Why he didn't I agree with @BP_Phoenix 's explanation, that he must make the ultimate sacrifice.

Comment: I may be wrong but I am sure the Shrieking Shack is in Hogsmeade where there are not disapparating restrictions, so being headmaster is not relevant here? :-)

Comment: Ohh, yeah, I guess you are right. So yeah your answer is just spot on. I just got confused.

Comment: I do realize I said, "Why could he just Disapparate into the castle?" I'm not about to edit my answer, and waste everybody's time, however, what about apparation into Hogsmead? He could then use a sort of apparation. This is far fetched, but i'm just curious.

Comment: I think this is the correct answer.  The Shrieking Shack was in Hogsmeade, but it was nonetheless part of the Hogwarts, and therefore covered by the restrictions against apparition and disapparition.  Severus was headmaster, and could lift the restrictions given time, but he didn't have enough time.  And even in the movies I believe the quote was "Being me has its advantages", not "being headmaster".

Comment: [Also relevant.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/149095/5930)